# What SQL Server 2017 Edition has the agent?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012, management-studio-express

Right now I have the express version and I need some automated work done and thus, I need the agent in my SSMS, my question is:

Which edition has the agent? On the website I've seen...

```
Enterprise, 
standard - per core,
standard - server + CAL,
Developer,
Web,
Express
```

Comment: Where on which website did you see that Express edition has the agent?

Comment: I didn't but now I need it

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question.   If Microsoft's website says that the Express edition includes the Agent, then that is an inaccuracy that you should report to them.

Comment: There will be a feature/edition  matrix on the Microsoft site that answers this. To be clear SSMS is a client tool though so is totally irrelevant to editions of the server product that come with SQL Agent.

Comment: @TabAlleman I think he is simply listing the versions available, not that the listed versions all have the agent.

Comment: @Steve-o169 You're probably right.  In that case this question is off-topic and inappropriate for Stack Overflow.   The right place to get this information is from the Microsoft website, where it will be kept up to date.  Not here where any answer would never change and get stale and possibly out of date.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Thanks, that was my intention and TabAlleman sorry if it was not clear

Comment: I can't see it on the Microsoft website which is why I'm asking here

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions

Comment: Or more relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017#SSMS

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks a bunch!! now I can see which has it and move on :D

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Express doesn't support SQL Server Agent.

SQL Server Enterprise, standard, Developer, Web all support SQL Server Agent.

By the way, You can also see the SQL Server Agent Service of the SQL Server Express instance in the Sql Server Configuration Manager. But you can't start it. You will get the error message like the below picture.

[image]